# Как запустить setInterval после clearInterval JavaScript

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, canvas

Подскажите, как бы начать заново игру после того, как ракетка промахивается по мячу.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("d1");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var pressedSpace = false;

// размеры ракетки
var playerWidth = 100;
var playerHeight = 7;

// расположение ракетки
var playerX = (canvas.width - playerWidth) / 2;;
var playerY = canvas.height - 15;

// мячик размеры и положение
var ballRadius = 5;
var ballX = canvas.width / 2;
var ballY = (canvas.height - ballRadius) / 2;
var ballDX = 3;
var ballDY = -3;

document.addEventListener("keydown", KeyDown, false);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", MouseMove, false);

// движение мышки
function MouseMove(e) {
  var relativeX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  if (relativeX > 0 && relativeX < canvas.width) {
    playerX = relativeX - playerWidth / 2;
  }
}

// нажатие пробела
function KeyDown(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    pressedSpace = true;
  }
}

// рисуем мячик
function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ballX, ballY, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

// рисуем ракетку
function drawPlayer() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

var loop = setInterval(function draw() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBall();
  drawPlayer();

  // нажимаем пробел
  if (pressedSpace) {

    // полетел мячик
    ballX += ballDX;
    ballY += ballDY;

    // проверка на столкновение боковых стенок
    if (ballX > canvas.width - ballRadius || ballX < ballRadius) {
      ballDX = -ballDX;
    }

    // проверка на столкновение с верхней стенкой
    else if (ballY < ballRadius) {
      ballDY = -ballDY;
    }

    // проверка на столкновение с нижней стенкой
    else if (ballY > playerY - ballRadius) {

      // если мячик коснулся ракетки
      if (ballX > playerX && ballX < playerX + playerWidth) {
        ballDY = -ballDY;
      }

      // если мячик не коснулся ракетки
      else if (ballY > playerY - ballRadius) {
        clearInterval(loop);
        // конец игры
      }
    }
  }
}, 10);
```

```css
#d1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="d1" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

P.S. чтобы запустить мячик нужно нажать пробел)
P.S.S. вариант document.location.reload() не подходит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо clearInterval лучше сбросить игру к начальному положению:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("d1");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var pressedSpace = false;

// размеры ракетки
var playerWidth = 100;
var playerHeight = 7;

// расположение ракетки
var playerX = (canvas.width - playerWidth)/2;;
var playerY = canvas.height - 15;

// мячик размеры и положение
var ballRadius = 5;
var ballX = canvas.width/2;
var ballY = (canvas.height-ballRadius)/2;
var ballDX = 3;
var ballDY = -3;

document.addEventListener("keydown", KeyDown, false);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", MouseMove, false);

// движение мышки
function MouseMove(e) {
  var relativeX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  if(relativeX > 0 && relativeX < canvas.width) {
    playerX = relativeX - playerWidth/2;
  }
}

// нажатие пробела
function KeyDown(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 32) {
    pressedSpace = true;
  }
}

// рисуем мячик
function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ballX, ballY, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

// рисуем ракетку
function drawPlayer() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

var loop = setInterval(function draw() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBall();
  drawPlayer();

  // нажимаем пробел
  if(pressedSpace) {

    // полетел мячик
    ballX += ballDX;
    ballY += ballDY;

    // проверка на столкновение боковых стенок
    if(ballX > canvas.width-ballRadius || ballX < ballRadius) {
      ballDX = -ballDX;
    }

    // проверка на столкновение с верхней стенкой
    else if(ballY < ballRadius) {
      ballDY = -ballDY;
    }

    // проверка на столкновение с нижней стенкой
    else if(ballY > playerY - ballRadius) {

      // если мячик коснулся ракетки
      if(ballX > playerX && ballX < playerX + playerWidth) {
        ballDY = -ballDY;
      }

      // если мячик не коснулся ракетки
      else if(ballY > playerY - ballRadius) {
        // конец игры
        pressedSpace = false;
        ballX = canvas.width/2;
        ballY = (canvas.height-ballRadius)/2;
        ballDX = 3;
        ballDY = -3;
      }
    }
  }
}, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="d1" width="400" height="300" ></canvas>
```